# page content in javascript needs to go in to html

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have links that when the user clicks them, the page immediately updates by utilizing the DOM, this is what my `o2()` does.

Problem is I want to seperate content from logic... i.e., i would prefer the content below to be in a .html file. Currently it is in a .js file.

My understanding is that it is good practice to keep structure/content seperate from logic... For example, using advanced registration for Javascript functions as opposed to inline registration.

How do I get the html content below into a .html file?

```
function l1() {
    o2('Ac1_3','<br/><p class="h">ALL YOUR BOOKMARKS IN ONE PLACE</p><img class="i1" src="i3.jpg" alt=""/><img class="i1" src="i4.jpg" alt=""/>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dynamically adding stuff to the DOM using JavaScript, there is *no way* around keeping that content in the JS file, unless you want to get pointlessly complex.

Personally, I think it's fine to mix content and logic a little, like this, just don't go over the top to the point where it gets confusing.

Comment: It's hard to say without context. In your situation, I'd keep your code in a `.js` file along with any other JavaScript you might have.